# Replace string with newline PHPStorm

Tags: replace, phpstorm

I cannot find a way to replace a string with a newline in PHPStorm.
Anybody has ideas?
Tried \n but it will just add the 2 characters instead of inserting a newline character.
Additional data following SolarBear answer
Here is the use case:

Original text:

```
"aaaaa","bbbbb","CCC",
some other text
```

Desired text

```
"aaaaa"=>"iiii",
"bbbbb"=>"iiii",
"CCC"=>"iiii",
```

some other text

When I try SolarBear solution, I select the "aaaa" line and select multiline, and have

```
,
```

in the top box and

```
 =>"iiii",
[newline]
```

in the second box. 
What happens is that the first "," is replaced, but curiously when I hit replace next "," PHPStorm replaces again the same "," Here is the output after hitting the replace button:

```
"aaaaa"=>"iiii"=>"iiii",

"bbbbb","CCCC"
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

- Search for: `,`
- Replace by: `=>"iiii",\n`
- **DO NOT FORGET** to check `Regex` option (as shown on 1st screenshot below)
- Hit **"Replace all"** button

**BEFORE:**
[image]

**AFTER:**
[image]

Answer (score 11):

**EDIT**

Checkout [@fromvega's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57364796/20043) if you have PhpStorm 2019, it is much more straightforwarrd. If your version is older, though, keep reading.

---

There is a way.

When you hit Ctrl-R to do a replace, click the Multiline icon (see the little white icon on the screenshot). You'll see two larger textboxes appear:

[image]

Just put a newline in the second box.

Comment: Thanks. We're getting close, but I hit a snag. I have updated the question.

Comment: I cannot find this button in PHPStorm 2019.1 (most recent version)

Comment: In PHPStorm 2019 use Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Comment: @fromvega : nice! I've linked to your answer, it's so much simpler.

Answer (score 8):

You have to check "Regex" and replace whatever you like with `\n`.

Comment: Yes, except the OP wants to replace something with a newline

Answer (score 6):

In PHPStorm 2019 you can add a new line by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` or by clicking in the New Line icon:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Update for anyone else, you can just click the highlighted `enter` icon below to do new line in search and replace;

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As SolarBear points out there is multi line functionality unfortunately there isn't a physical tick box in many variations of intellij for whatever reason.

so for those like me wondering how to so activate it. It can be accessed by using ALT+Enter when in the text field. it will then turn into a multi line replace tool which will accept anything.

[image]